# Type of properties in a generic function

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I'm trying to transform some fields of my object by providing field names, currently I wrote something like follows:

```js
interface Foo {
    a: number[],
    b: string[],
}

type Bar = { [T in keyof Foo] : (arg : Foo[T]) => Foo[T] }

function test<T extends keyof Foo>(field: T) {
    const foo : Foo = {
        a: [],
        b: [],
    };

    const bar: Bar = {
        a: arg => /* some code */ [],
        b: arg => /* some code */ [],
    };

    foo[field] = bar[field](foo[field]);
}
```

But I end up with the following error message on `bar[field](foo[field])`:

```
Argument of type 'Foo[T]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[] & string[]'.
  Type 'number[] | string[]' is not assignable to type 'number[] & string[]'.
    Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number[] & string[]'.
      Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          Type 'Foo[T]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
            Type 'number[] | string[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
              Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
                Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

But shouldn't typescript "know" that with the same `T`, `Foo[T]` and `Parameters<Bar[T]>` should be the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: How to map objects in a discriminated union to functions they can be called with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56781010/typescript-how-to-map-objects-in-a-discriminated-union-to-functions-they-can-be)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argument of type {…} is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56406284/argument-of-type-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never/56409709)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the compiler should know that, but it doesn't.  I tend to call this issue "correlated types" or "correlated records".  The compiler sees `foo[field]` and `bar[field]` as union-typed things, which is true enough.  But it treats their types as independent, meaning that as far as it knows, `foo[field]` might be `number[]` while `bar[field]` might be a function that takes `string[]`.  It doesn't see that the type of  `foo[field]` is *correlated* to the type of `bar[field]` in such a way that knowing one fixes the other.  There's an open issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) (which I filed, fwiw) suggesting that there be some support for correlated types, but it's not clear if that's ever going to happen or how.

All we have right now are workarounds.  The two workarounds mentioned in that issue: either use redundant code to force the compiler to walk through the different possibilities and guarantee type safety, or use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to give up on some type safety but maintain brevity.  For your code it would look like this:

```
// redundant code
const f: keyof Foo = field;
switch (f) {
   case "a":
      foo[f] = bar[f](foo[f]);
      break;
   case "b":
      foo[f] = bar[f](foo[f]);
      break;
}

// type assertion
foo[field] = (bar[field] as <T>(arg: T) => T)(foo[field]);
```

I usually opt for the type assertion.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkFwBcyIArgLYBG0A2gLoA0+BVJAzmFKAOYPMBfZLlxgAngAcUAIThRkAXhzJaAFWShkAawhj0MNJnokAFHJ4kM6NfQCUigHyHrq+sgEiYZEAjDB0IMiQnAA86hAAHpAgACbs2rr6zg4mMMAQADYxJKr2eATICAGcyDCYlpiKOCwFyMQqTDUFbA3MBQIA3CIFRSAlVHIksvJK+bV1JOaOyAD0AFTI7OgUKEUxKHMz-E2sk1A80-OLy6vo68ib2+1dNTMzyFAQMd4xcOCFZxA1vSUwJDp6AxWKppTIxLoFdgAd2AYAQAAtkKk8jtCnB2CgAERwTFEVEFMrWGBuJQDKC0YmpTAUuwQ8bNR5wLR02oIdFYqi4-EEQk0qpkmlUom07nIKiM5k1Dy3e7iKR1dgYqB+AI1XmgrIkpECjUxNzo5BhFLmHL2BROXJCinpTW2LrSoA)