# How to type two objects that share the same keys between two objects in typescript?

Tags: typescript

EDIT:

This question has been marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59077562/type-of-properties-in-a-generic-function). I don't see anything related in this other question.

---

Two interfaces `IObjectA` and `IObjectB` share the same keys `foo` and `bar`:

```js
// types
interface IObjectFoo { code: number }
interface IObjectBar { name: string }
type IFunctionFoo = () => IObjectFoo
type IFunctionBar = () => IObjectBar

interface IObjectA {
    foo: IFunctionFoo
    bar: IFunctionBar
} 

type IObjectAKeys = keyof IObjectA

interface IObjectB {
    foo?: IObjectFoo
    bar?: IObjectBar
}

// code
const objectA = {
    foo: () => ({ code: 127 }),
    bar: () => ({ name: 'Louise Michel' })
} as IObjectA

const someFilter = (obj: string) => ['foo'].includes(obj)

const keys = Object.keys(objectA).filter(someFilter) as IObjectAKeys[]

const objectB = keys.reduce((acc: IObjectB, key) => {
    const functionFooOrBar = objectA[key]

    // error : Type '{ code: number; } | { name: string; }' is not assignable to type '(IObjectFoo & IObjectBar) | undefined'.
    acc[key] = functionFooOrBar()

    return acc
}, {})
```

There is an error on `acc[key] =`.

I would like typecript to understand that if the value of `key` is `foo`, then `functionFooOrBar` is of type `IFunctionFoo`.

How is it possible to achieve that?

Here is [the repro on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-elbakyan-mm9bs?file=/index.ts)

Comment: I got the error to dissappear by adding type asertion `acc[key] = functionFooOrBar() as IObjectFoo & IObjectBar;`

Comment: you could also do `const functionFooOrBar = objectA[key as 'foo'];` `acc[key as 'foo'] = functionFooOrBar()` if you know for sure that `key === 'foo'`

Comment: @uranshishko thank you very much, this works! Please answer the question with your first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the error to dissappear by adding type asertion acc[key] = functionFooOrBar() as IObjectFoo & IObjectBar;

you could also do const functionFooOrBar = objectA[key as 'foo']; acc[key as 'foo'] = functionFooOrBar() if you know for sure that key === 'foo'

Doing this also works

```
const objectB = keys.reduce((acc: IObjectB, key) => {
  let functionFooOrBar;

  if(key === 'foo') {
    functionFooOrBar = objectA[key];

    acc[key] = functionFooOrBar();
  }  

  return acc;
}, {});
```