# TypeScript Class method argument with Generic Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm having trouble to achieve a type problem on method argument. Here's similar code i have same error:

```
class Const<I> {
  mapItems(newItems: I[]) {
    console.log(newItems);
  }
}

interface First {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

interface Second {
  c: string;
  d: string;
}

type Key = 'first' | 'second';

const consts = {
  first: new Const<First>(),
  second: new Const<Second>(),
};

const randomKey = (): Key => {
  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'first' : 'second';
};

const firstItems = [
  {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
  },
];

const secondItems = [
  {
    c: 'c',
    d: 'd',
  },
];

const items = {
  first: firstItems,
  second: secondItems,
};

const key = randomKey();
const constr = consts[key];
const constrItems = items[key];

constr.mapItems(constrItems);
              // Error here
```

Full Error is

```
Argument of type '{ a: string; b: string; }[] | { c: string; d: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'First[] & Second[]'.
  Type '{ a: string; b: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'First[] & Second[]'.
    Type '{ a: string; b: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Second[]'.
      Type '{ a: string; b: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Second': c, d
    ts(2345)
```

I understand that problem is you never guarantee, you call with right type of `items`. But, how can i achieve something like this?

Comment: Looks like another [correlated union types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) issue.  I suggest you use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and move on: `(constr as Const<First | Second>).mapItems(constrItems);`

Comment: I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of one of the other questions that runs into this issue (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082214/typescript-inference-without-enumerating-all-possibilities) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56406284/argument-of-type-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never/56409709#56409709) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59077562/type-of-properties-in-a-generic-function) etc).  If you think it is a different issue, please elaborate.  Good luck!

Comment: Note that `Const<First | Second>` is more permissive than what the topic starter tries to represent, so it opens a possibility to incorrect behavior

Comment: @amakhrov Very true.  The linked github issue and possible-duplicates above go through the whole issue: there's no safe way to represent what OP is doing without adding a bunch of redundant code; at least with the current version of TS the type assertion is probably the least bad way to proceed, albeit with caution.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you i've did it by using union type `type AllTypes = First | Second` then used it `const constr = consts[key] as AllTypes` and it worked! I understand what you're pointing out! Cheers!

Comment: @amakhrov That's right. It seems impossible to establish that i have the right type of argument  to TypeScript compiler and it's kind of cheap hack. But i really used to use this kind of mappings in JavaScript. Maybe i should improve myself to use different type safe architectures. Kind of beginner with typed systems.